# Using iTextSharp to generate multiple page PDF from existing PDF Form

Tags: itext

I have a fillable PDF form which needs to be programatically filled for each member and added to a single pdf document.

I am able to use pdfstamper to read the existing pdf, and change the data, but I cant seem to figure out how to create multiple instances of the pdfstamper with different data in the same pdf doc.

Answer (score 3):

You don't.  One PDF stamper->1 document OUTPUT.  You didn't give a lot of detail, but your workflow will probably need to be something like this:

For Each PDF form:
* Open it with a Stamper
* Fill it in
* turn on flattening
* Save it (to memory or disk)

Create a PdfCopy (or SmartCopy)

For each intermediate PDF
 * Insert it into Pdf*Copy

Save your final doc.

---

None too efficient, but that's how it works with iText.

PS: You really do need to flatten your forms when merging multiple forms together, PARTICULARLY when you have multiple copies of the same form.  In a PDF, fields that share a name also share a value.